# Fetch as Googlebot returning an empty body in Meteor

Tags: meteor, seo, phantomjs

I have no problems with spiderable package, I followed everything written here http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable or here http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteor-and-seo or here http://journal.gentlenode.com/meteor-12-seo-guide. I am deploying in meteor.com. Both using curl and browsing to http://myapp.meteor.com/?_escaped_fragment_= is working correctly.

However, I am still getting an empty body with the Google's fetch-as-googlebot (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) or with the Facebook debug (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) or the Twitter Debug (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator) or Woorank (http://www.woorank.com/).

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Did you figure something out? - got the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you website is compliant with Google guideline on Making AJAX Applications Crawlable.

You can learn more here

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: The spiderable package is already compliant with the guidelines, check http://docs.meteor.com/#spiderable